# Find elements with class "x", ignore elements with "x" and more classes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have HTML that looks something like this:

```
<span class="x">Text 1</span>
<span class="x y">Text 2</span>
<span class="x">Text 3</span>
<span class="x z">Text 4</span>
```

I can use this to find all children with the class `x`:

```
for span_text in soup_subset.findChildren('span', class_='x'):
    print (span_text)
```

This will output text of span elements with just the `x` class, as well as those with `x` and another class.

How do I find children with just the `x` class, ignoring those that have `x` and some other class?

Answer (score 0):

Use  a CSS selector to get *span* tags with only that class.

```
soup.select("span[class='x']")
```

Code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html ="""
<span class="x">Text 1</span>
<div class="x">Div Text 1</div>
<span class="x y">Text 2</span>
<span class="x">Text 3</span>
<span class="x z">Text 4</span>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.select("span[class='x']"))
```

Output

```
[<span class="x">Text 1</span>, <span class="x">Text 3</span>]
```

**Ref**

- https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors